# How to extract words including Double Quotes to a list LIKE GOOGLE in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a search feature of a web site. I need to extract an user input kind of a sentence to a list but requires words in quotes should be an item of the list.

Please focus on the words **Jeff Watson** and **New York** in my expectation.

Expectation:

```
str = 'Hello, I am "Jeff Watson" from a part of "New York".'

result = ["Hello", "I", "am", "Jeff Watson", "from", "a", "part", "of", "New York"]
```

It's the best if your answer works with single quotes as well.

Comment: Loads of ways you can do this. For example `spacy` will do this automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks @Simon, it looks what I have looked for! But I could not find the exact method(most of them look omit several words). I'd like to use it and dive into the morphological world. Can you specify a method name, please?

Answer (score 5):

A regexp looking for either quoted substrings or words:

```
import re
string = 'Hello, I am "Jeff Watson" from NY.'
[next(x for x in m if x)
    for m in re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\'|(\w+)', string)]
```

(Also, try to avoid using `str` as a variable name in Python, as it normally holds the string type.)

Here's another method:

```
[m[1] for m in re.findall(r'(["\'])?((?(1).*?\1|\w+))', string)]
```

Comment: Thank you @Amadan! Could you improve with multiple quoted words like 'Hello, I am "Jeff Watson" from "New York".'?

Comment: What improvement would you have me do? It already should handle your example.

Comment: oh it was wrong. How about this?

Hello, I am "Jeff Watson" from your country "New York".

I got ' from your country ' as an item

Comment: Apologies, indeed I did not think of that. I revised the answer.

Comment: No apologies! My question was wrong. It worked, your answer is amazing. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

a very rookie solution

```
s = 'Hello, I am "Jeff Watson" from NY.'
ans = []
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    if s[i].isalnum():
        temp = ""
        while s[i].isalnum():
            temp += s[i]
            i += 1
        ans.append(temp)
    if s[i] == '"':
        temp = '"'
        i += 1
        while s[i] != '"':
            temp += s[i]
            i += 1
        temp += '"'
        ans.append(temp)
    i += 1

print(ans)
```